# How to generate a CSV file in a background task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, background-process

We allow users to download all of their data in CSV format, but we're finding that for a lot of users (who have a lot of data) we really need to generate the CSV file in the background and then provide them a link to download it later.

I know how to generate a CSV file on the fly *in the view*, but I'm not totally clear on the best way to generate it in a background task.

I'm currently using [csv_builder](https://github.com/dasil003/csv_builder) to generate CSV files in the view...so it'd be awesome to be able to still use that and just somehow output that directly into a CSV file that I can then upload to S3 using paperclip...but that might be too far-fetched.

Comment: backgroundrb should help you. they have described steps how to perform some task in the background. you could automate it to run it based on when you need it(before you use it in the view you could generate it) using cron.

Comment: I know how to run background tasks. I'm asking how to generate a CSV file using a background task and if it's possible to keep using `csv_builder`

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, but used the built in rails CSV library rather than csv_builder (which I know nothing about).

in my model I have a method for generating a csv and saving as paerclip attachment on s3:

```
def csv_export
  @entries = self.entries    
  @filename = "naming my file"    
  CSV.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{@filename}", "wb") do |csv| #creates a tempfile csv
    csv << ["Date & Time", "Name", "Email"] #creates the header
    @entries.each do |e|            
      csv << [e.created_at, e.name, e.email] #create new line for each item in collection
    end
end

self.update_attribute(:csv_report, File.open("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{@filename}"))
  #saves tempfile as paperclip attachment
end
```

I invoke this method in a rake task that offloads to a delayed job worker.

So in the rake task: `Object.delay.csv_export`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a database table where you can save the file after its made in the background. I can show you the rails migration.

```
  create_table "csv_table", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.binary "csv_file"
    t.string "file_name"
  end
```

After creating this You can save your csv file here. You can save your file into binary by using

```
csv_converted_file = Base64.encode64(csv)
```

Here csv is the data.

Now, if you want to download your csv in background. You can download this by using this coffee script. You will make an ajax request to get the data of csv you just saved in your csv table.

```
   $.ajax
    type: 'GET'
    dataType: "text"
    url: url
    success: (data) ->
      blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/csv" })
      file_name_url = new URL(window.location.href)
      file_name = file_name_url.searchParams.get("file_name");
      url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      a = document.createElement('a')
      a.setAttribute('hidden', '')
      a.setAttribute('href', url)
      a.setAttribute('download', file_name)
      document.body.appendChild(a)
      a.click()
      document.body.removeChild(a)
  return
```

By this, Your csv will be downloaded on desired page load.